# How do I create certificates in Azure for a custom domain?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-functions, lets-encrypt

**I am trying to follow [this](https://samcogan.com/lets-encrypt-certificates-in-azure-with-acmebotot/) tutorial to create certificates in Azure for a custom domain. I have the same issue as Marc:**
[image]

**However, I *have* set access to DNS  Zone already:**

[image]
**Could the problem be that is it a custom Domain? If so any workaround, if not anything else to check?**

Comment: Do you want to create a certificate for your Windows web application on the Azure app service?

Comment: No it is a cert for a static website in a storage account.

Comment: But, that tutorial you followed is mentioned that "there is a plugin for Azure Web Apps, but this only works for Windows web applications". You may edit your question to describe your issue more clearly?

Comment: Well, maybe I should read it properly next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [tutorial](https://samcogan.com/lets-encrypt-certificates-in-azure-with-acmebotot/) you followed mentioned that "there is a plugin for Azure Web Apps, but this only works for Windows web applications", so you may not follow that steps.

To create a certificate for the static website in a storage account, you can follow [this blog1](https://robertkroll.name/2020/03/26/enable-https-with-lets-encrypt-on-azure-static-site.html)---Enable HTTPS with Lets Encrypt on Azure static site and read [this blog2](https://wrightfully.com/azure-static-website-custom-domain-https) for more details.

An Azure static site hosted on a storage container allows you to have a free certificate provided by DigiCert but only for subdomains (such as www). If you want to use the root domain, it's available for using the Bring your own certificate feature. You need to [configure HTTPS on an Azure CDN custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-2-enable-https-with-your-own-certificate#register-azure-cdn).

There is an amazing project [lets-encrypt-azure](https://github.com/MarcStan/lets-encrypt-azure) on GitHub that allows you can run as an Azure Function that will provide this endpoint, download the certificate to an Azure Key vault to be used by your CDN.

Comment: Thank you! The one I ended up using was: https://dev.to/shibayan/the-fastest-way-to-use-let-s-encrypt-in-azure-58pk